# Is it normal that java file-name syntax changes after compiling?? ( like Matrix.java to matrix.class)

Tags: java, syntax

I was going through some basics and wrote the following code for 2D array and saved it under 'Matrix.java' name. Then I compiled it in CMD and found that `Matrix.java` is been converted to `matrix.class`. Is this normal?

As per my knowledge *Java compiler* does not change the *file-name syntax*. And I never faced such thing previously, am I missing something here?

I can not post the image of the screenshot of `CMD` because of the low reputation marks here :/

```
//Initialize a Two Dimensional Array
class matrix {
    public static void main( String args[]){
        double matrix[][] = {
           { 0*0, 1*0, 2*0,3*0},
           { 0*1, 1*1, 2*1,3*1},
           { 0*2, 1*2, 2*2,3*2},
           { 0*3, 1*3, 2*3,3*3},            
        };

        int i,j;

        //printing the array 
        for(i=0; i<4; i++){
           for(j=0; j<4; j++){
               System.out.print(matrix[i][j] +" ");
           }
           System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of your class name class matrix. Java compiler create class file from those.
Java recommend to use java class name and file name should same exactly.

Comment: you're welcome :) and don't upset so much.Great developer had so many mistake in pass.

Answer (score 0):

Mess up with upper and lower Char in Class name and File name. Your class should be named exactly the same as the file:

```
//Initialize a Two Dimensional Array
class Matrix {
public static void main( String args[]){
    double matrix[][] = {
        { 0*0, 1*0, 2*0,3*0},
        { 0*1, 1*1, 2*1,3*1},
```